# How to pass a function to a component using arrow function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

FYI: I am using ES6 on ReactJS

I have a switcher. I need it to switch to the other side when clicked.
If click on the side that is currently active does nothing.

Here is my sample code

```
import { useState } from 'react'
const {isLeftButton, setIsLeftButton} = useState(true);
const toggleSwitcher = () => {
    setIsLeftButton(!isLeftButton)
}

const home = () => {
...
    return (
        <CustomSwitcher isLeftButton={isLeftButton} toggleSwitcher={toggleSwitcher} />
    )
...
}
export default Home
```

Here is the code inside the `CustomSwitcher`

```
const CustomSwitcher = (isLeftButton, toggleSwitcher) => {

    const leftButton = () => {
        if (isLeftButton !== true) {
            toggleSwitcher()
        }
    }

    const rightButton = (isLeftButton, toggleSwitcher) => {
        if (isRightButton === true) {
            toggleSwitcher()
        }
    }

    return (
         <div>
             <CustomButton onClick={LeftButton}>Left Button</CustomButton>
             <CustomButton onClick={rightButton }>Right Button</CustomButton>
         </div>
        )
    }
export default CustomSwitcher
```

However I got this error

```
TypeError: toggleSwitcheris not a function
  12 |    const CustomSwitcher = () => {
  13 |        
  14 |        if (leftButton !== true) {
> 15 |            toggleSwitcher()
     | ^  16 |        }
  17 |    }
  18 |
```

As I understand, when passing a function down to a component. The function is no longer a function.

And I don't think my code is good. If you can think of a better way to do so. Please contribute.

Comment: Can you try this in your `CustomSwitcher` arguments. `({isLeftButton, toggleSwitcher})` typically a props object is the argument a component is expecting, not individual props.

Comment: props are passed as properties of the first argument, not as a list of arguments to the component. Make your CuastomSwitcher props `{ isLeftButton, toggleSwitcher }`

Also, you have a typo in the name of your onClick handler for leftbutton

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not using the correct way to access the props.

Try to replace

```
const CustomSwitcher = (isLeftButton, toggleSwitcher) => {
```

with

```js
const CustomSwitcher = ({isLeftButton, toggleSwitcher}) => {
```

Answer (score 1):

`const CustomSwitcher = (isLeftButton, toggleSwitcher) => { ... }`

is not the correct way to build a component.

Either use the props object

```
const CustomSwitcher = (props) => {
    // props.toggleSwitcher
}
```

Or destructure props

```
cost CustomSwitcher = ({isLeftButton, toggleSwitcher}) => { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `useState` inside a functional component. In your case, inside `home`. [Hooks cannot be used at the global level](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html#rules-of-hooks).
Consequently, you need to define `toggleSwitcher` inside `home` also.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).